# Navigation issue in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view(HomeView) in which i open a popOver. The popoVer content View is (ListView) which contains a Table View.

Now, when i select the row, The HomeView will dismissed & open a new View(MapView).

Till now, It works fine. But my all views contain tabbar in xib. I don't have tab bar in ListView.

So, i just open MapView with present Modal View. But from that my navigation is not working.

My code is as following.

**HomeView.m**

//open popview with ListView

```
-(IBAction)btnTableMenu_TouchUpInside:(id)sender{

ListView *popUp=[[ListView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListView" bundle:nil];



    popView = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popUp];
    popView.delegate =self;

    [popView setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 700)];
    [popView presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(150,25,20,50) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

**ListView.m**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DismissModal"object:self];

    MapViewController *mapVC=[[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController_ipad" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:mapVC animated:YES];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapVC animated:YES];
}
```

**How can i solve this??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just do like this way:-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DismissModal"object:self];

    MapViewController *mapVC=[[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController_ipad" bundle:nil]; 
    UINavigationController *navbar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mapVC];
    navbar.navigationBar.tintColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:108/255.0 blue:61/255.0 alpha:0.1];


    [navbar setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [navbar setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

    [self presentModalViewController:navbar animated:YES];

}
```

in `MapViewController.m` file `ViewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *CancleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = CancleButton;

}

-(void)cancel
{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  

}
```

Comment: But i don't want to make new navigation Controller. How can i use Existing Navigation Bar?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the difference btw .. 
`[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];` 
& `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];`

\When you do presentModalViewController:controller you lost the last Navigation stack.You need to create different navigationController for presenting the View.  Read this properly you will get Idea .

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: i know but is there any other solution to do it.

Comment: Yes , it is ..
You use animation blocks inside you can use [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
Give the animation like it is presenting view as a model.Then navigation will work. I have done this in my previous projects.

Comment: but i open the List View which contains a Table in popover & in this view i don't have navigation controller Object.

Comment: ok.. then i think you need to create different navigationController for presenting the View. or else i don't know. :|

Comment: i put the code of it but i dont know @user1673099 not want to create another NavigationViewcontroller. if you want to display navigationControler in PresentModelViewcontroler you must need to crate new NavigationController

Comment: @NitinGohel, i know but without creating new navController, is that possible??

Comment: no its not posible i lot google it and i found new navigationController creation otherwise app cresh

Comment: i am getting same prob then i give some animation while presenting modelViewcontroller with `[navbar setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];` and 
    `[navbar setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];` then client says well done :) lolz

Answer (score 0):

Try following these-

**ListView.m**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DismissModal"object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"map" forKey:@"selectedView"]];
}
```

**HomeView.m**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissModal:) name:@"DismissModal" object:nil];


- (void) dismissModal:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self dismissModalViewController:mapVC animated:NO];

    if([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"selectedView"] isEqualToString:@"map"])
    {
        MapViewController *mapVC=[[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController_ipad" bundle:nil]; 
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mapVC];
        [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    }
}
```